# How to pass custom data for use in MDX using next-mdx-remote/rsc in Nextjs 13.4

Tags: next.js

In the non RSC version of next-mdx-remote, I could pass custom data for use inside .mdx by passing the data to a `scope` prop like so:

`<MDXRemote {...source} components={components} scope={data} />`

But with next-mdx-remote/rsc the scope prop doesn't seem to be working:

```
const source = fs.readFileSync(mdxPath, 'utf8')
const {content, data} = matter(source)
const customData = { product: 'next' }


return (

<MDXRemote source={content} components={...components} scope={customData} />
)
```

When I try to access `{product}` inside mdx it says `product is not defined`

What's the correct way to send custom data through next-mdx-remote/rsc? Also is there a way to combine scope into the source like how you would do by passing scope to the serialize method in the past?

Tried passing scope into

Tried merging custom data to the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDXRemote from `next-mdx-remote/rsc` accepts the `scope` parameter inside the `options` prop.

```js
<MDXRemote
  source={content}
  components={components}
  options={{ scope: customData }}
/>
```

Comment: Incredible thank you!